# Two identical TableLayout's identical TableRow's not showing equal android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I created two identical `TableLayout`'s in my xml file

And programmatically added two Identical(everything is same except variable names) `TableRows` with `TextView`'s but they're not showing the same in app.

Here's the xml and the image:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/detected_drones"
        android:textSize = "25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black">
    </TextView>

    //FIRST TABLELAYOUT
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/zaberlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">
    </TableLayout>

    //SECOND TABLELAYOUT
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/naberlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/zaberlist"//ONLY DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THEM
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="@string/start_scan"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanBtnStop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="@string/stop_scan"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcovT.png)

edit:
here's how I add those rows to the table:

```kotlin
                val tr_head1 = TableRow(this@WIFIScannerActivity)
                tr_head1.layoutParams = TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )

                val label_name1 = TextView(this@WIFIScannerActivity)
                label_name1.text = scanResult.SSID
                if(scanResult.SSID==""){
                    label_name1.text = "*hidden*"
                }
                label_name1.textSize = 14F
                label_name1.layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1F)
                label_name1.setPadding(20,0,0,0)
                label_name1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
                tr_head1.addView(label_name1) // add the column to the table row here

                val label_mac1 = TextView(this@WIFIScannerActivity) // part3
                label_mac1.text = scanResult.BSSID
                label_mac1.textSize = 14F
                label_mac1.layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1F)
                label_mac1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
                tr_head1.addView(label_mac1) // add the column to the table row here

                val label_distance1 = TextView(this@WIFIScannerActivity) // part3
                label_distance1.text = String.format("%.2f", Math.pow(10.0, (((-20 - scanResult.level).toDouble())/20)))//Math.pow(10.0, ((-20 - scanResult.level.toDouble()) / 20)).toString()
                label_distance1.textSize = 14F
                label_distance1.layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1F)
                label_distance1.setPadding(0,0,20,0)
                label_distance1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
                tr_head1.addView(label_distance1)



                tr_head1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
                tr_head1.setPadding(0,10,0,10)

                //I only change xdlist here to add to different tables
                xdlist!!.addView(tr_head1, TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                ))
```

Comment: You need to share the code that you add the `TableRow` s to the TableLayout, as an minor difference in the size of the contents of the table will cause the two independent tables to behave differently.

Comment: @Andrew sorry, done

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the two tables is identical (including spaces) then in theory the results should be the same for the two tables BUT in real usage it's unlikely that you would be displaying the identical data in two tables next to each other.

So if you want to align column's correctly just use one `TableLayout` and multiple `TableRow` items, because a `TableLayout` is only designed to align within each Table and not between tables.

Alternative use a different type of Layout, probably better to be one based on a `RecyclerView`, or a `ConstraintLayout`, but with understanding all the type of data and how you want the data to be presented I cannot advise on the best method.

Comment: Can I make just one row's position fixed in `ScrollView`? because I want a header row

Comment: TableLayout does not offer the functionality to fix a header, more commonly this is done with a recylerview with a fixed header, but if you really want to align two TableLayout type Tables then the Library https://github.com/Zardozz/FixedHeaderTableLayout has a Bonus feature that allows you to use the auto sizing of a TableLayout but then adjust the column widths to align multiple tables.